# ImageMagick: How to do limit colors and dither

Tags: imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to create a GIF Animation from several frames of a video. I want the result to be small by limiting the colors, but without banding.

So, in my mind, I thought of reading the files, then reducing the colors, then dithering. After reading a whole lot of ImageMagick theory of operation on their website, this is the command line I came up with:

```
convert -size 640x640 -colors 64 *.png -ordered-dither o8x8,8,8,4 +map \
  -layers Optimize output.gif
```

The `.png` files were generated from the video using `ffmpeg` like this:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 10:01.123 -to 10:03.321 frames/source_%03d.png
```

I'm not really sure where to put the `-colors 64` clause though. Should I put it before the `*.jpg` part or after? Or even after the `-ordered-dither o8x8,8,8,4` part?

Thank you for any help. I'm quite new to ImageMagick, so please be gentle :-)

---

**Update 1:**

So, I played around and got these unintuitive (to me) results:

```
-delay 12 -colors 128 *.png -resize 640x640 -ordered-dither o8x8,8 -deconstruct +map \
  -layers Optimize output_1.gif
Result: 3.09 MB, Good quality

-delay 12 *.png -colors 128 -resize 640x640 -ordered-dither o8x8,8 -deconstruct +map \
  -layers Optimize output_2.gif
Result: 3.09 MB, Good quality

-delay 12 *.png -resize 640x640 -colors 128 -ordered-dither o8x8,8 -deconstruct +map \
  -layers Optimize output_3.gif
Result: 4.41 MB, Degraded quality

-delay 12 *.png -resize 640x640 -ordered-dither o8x8,8 -colors 128 -deconstruct +map \
  -layers Optimize output_4.gif
Result: 2.77 MB, Good quality

-delay 12 <individual .png followed by -colors 128 each> -resize 640x640 \
  -ordered-dither o8x8,8 -colors 128 -deconstruct +map -layers Optimize output_5.gif
Result: 3.09 MB, Slightly Better quality
```

In short: All combinations produce really good quality except the #3 combination, which not only produced a visibly degraded result, but also the largest.

This is quite unexpected... what do you think: How could the result varied wildly like this?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the manual for ImageMagick [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#anatomy)

> ### The Anatomy of the Command-line
>
> The ImageMagick command-line consists
>   of:
>
> one or more required input filenames.
>
> zero, one, or more image settings.
>
> zero, one, or more image operators.
>
> zero, one, or more image sequence operators.
>
> zero, one, or more image stacks.
>
> zero or one output image filenames (required by convert, composite, montage,
>   compare, import, conjure).
>
> You can find a detailed explanation of each
>   of the constituent parts of the command-line in the sections that
>   follow.

Whether it matters too much, I don't know, but this implies you'd structure it as such:

```
convert  *.png -size 640x640 -colors 64 -ordered-dither o8x8,8,8,4 +map -layers optimize output.gif
```

I tested this command and it worked fine, converted 4x PNG files @ 6-7MB each into a GIF of 5.2MB.

Comment: Eh? I did include `-` on `-layers` ... also what is the proper spelling, `Optimize` or `optimize`? Or does it not matter for this particular keyword?

Comment: Anyways, thank you for pointing out that "anatomy" section to me! I must have missed that particular page --__--

Comment: @pepoluan Whoops, not sure why I thought you didn't, must have copy and pasted it wrong! Sorry! Typically lowercase, but it depends on the specifications (textually they're the same, but binary comparisons would fail, so keep it the same where possible)